# My forEach statement is repeating more than it should

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase and react js. my forEach loop is only supposed to repeat for the number of objects I have stored in the firebase database but instead of repeated the expected 3 times it will repeat 8 or 9 or something like that. Also when I run the code a second time it will repeat super fast and fill up my console.

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        warmupList: [],
        title: "",
        id: ""
    }
}

handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        title: e.target.value
    })
}

SetActiveWarmup(id) {
    const warmupRef = firebase.database().ref("Warmups")
    warmupRef.on("value",(snapshot) => {
        const warmups = snapshot.val()
```

this is where the for each is

```
        Object.keys(warmups).forEach(key => {
            if(id === key) {
                warmupRef.child(key).update({
                    activity: "True"
            })
            } else {
                warmupRef.child(key).update({
                        activity: "False"
                })
            }
            console.log("has run")
        })
    })
}

createWarmup = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(this.state.title === "") return
    const warmupRef = firebase.database().ref("Warmups")
    var key = warmupRef.push().key
    warmupRef.child(key).set({
        title: this.state.title,
        activity: "True",
        id: key
    }) 
    this.setState({
        title: ""
    })
}

componentWillMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    const warmupRef = firebase.database().ref("Warmups")
    warmupRef.on("value",(snapshot) => {
        const warmups = snapshot.val()
        const warmupList = []
        for(let id in warmups) {
            warmupList.push(warmups[id])
        }
        this.setState({
            warmupList: warmupList
        })
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={`warmup${this.props.activity}`}>
            <div className="newWarmup__bottom">
                <form onSubmit={this.createWarmup}>
                    <input placeholder="My Warmup..."
                    value={this.state.title} 
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    <CircleButton click={this.createWarmup} 
                    Icon={AddIcon} color="Green" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="warmup__select">
                {this.state.warmupList.map(warmup => 
                    <SelectWarmup key={v4()} 
                    text={warmup.title} 
                    activity={warmup.activity}
                    click={() => this.SetActiveWarmup(warmup.id)} />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: try `console.log(key)` in the forEach ... what do you see ... perhaps `warmupRef.on("value",(snapshot) => {` is being triggered more than once, try `console.log(warmups)` before the `forEach` - what do you see now

Comment: What would cause it to run more than once

Comment: did you do what I suggested to debug the data you are getting

Comment: I did do what you suggested and the first time I pressed it consoled twice then the second time I ran it it console three times and so on until I refreshed the page.

Comment: somewhere you keep adding an event listener without removing the old one? I can't see it in the code you posted, but, that would explain it